# How does the Soul Siphon perk work?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

The rightmost line of perks in the Enchanting constellation terminates with a perk called Soul Siphon, which causes your deathblows on creatures (but NOT people) to trap 5% of the victim. What does this mean? Does this require you to have an unused soul gem in inventory for it to work, and how does it interact with a soul trap weapon?

Comment: I was also wondering about the soul trap enchantment overlap. It would imply that either you catch 105% of the soul, or only get 95% in the gem...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> What does this mean?

It means, you can take out your completely empty Sword of Flaming Flames, kill a bear with it, and now it's got 5% of the bear's soul for the next fight.  (note: works for partially filled magic items too)

> Does this require you to have an unused soul gem in inventory for it to work

Nope.

> and how does it interact with a soul trap weapon?

1. The soul trap weapon casts soul trap on the creature.
2. The creature dies.
3. 5% of the creature's soul is stored to the weapon.
4. 100% of the creature's soul is stored to an empty gem.

Yes, that is 105% of the soul, which is awesome.

Comment: I think the only disadvantage is that it doesn't increase the enchanting skill

Answer (score 9):

That description seems off, or at least misleading. The full perk description is:

> Death blows to creatures, but not people, trap 5% of the victim's soul, recharging the weapon.

The *Soul Siphon* perk isn't meant to trap souls in the normal sense (like you would with *Soul Trap*), it's meant to be an automatic recharge for your enchanted weapon.

Skizzlefrits [mentions in the comments](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36869/how-does-the-soul-siphon-perk-work#comment-53692) how it works:

> It would recharge the weapon for 5% of the amount that a soul gem filled with that soul would recharge. So this is a good perk to have at higher levels when you are fighting enemies that would fill grand soul gems.

Comment: that calculation is slightly off... it doesn't recharge 5% of the weapons charge. It would recharge the weapon for 5% of the amount that a soulgem filled with that soul would recharge. so this is a good perk to have at higher levels when you are fighting enemies that would fill grand soul gems

Comment: @Skizzlefrits Ah, interesting: that makes sense. The description could be a lot clearer.

Comment: Realistically: any weapon with 20 or more charges is self sustaining against enemies that provide souls equivalent to the one used to craft the weapon. Which is kind of amazing.

Comment: ...provided that you one-shot them every time. If not, you're using more than one charge to kill them, but only getting one back when they die.